# how to check if two doubles are equal in java

Tags: java

I am writing a program to help students practice division, how can I compare the user Input and the correct answer if they are doubles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert it to BigDecimal, and compare with the required precision of decimal places

```
BigDecimal aa = new BigDecimal(a);
BigDecimal bb = new BigDecimal(b);
aa = aa.setScale(4, BigDecimal.ROUND_DOWN);
bb = bb.setScale(4, BigDecimal.ROUND_DOWN);
return aa.equals(bb);
```

Answer (score 0):

Either use

```
Double.compare()
```

or

```
final double EPSILON = 0.00000001d;
Math.abs(firstDouble - secondDouble) < EPSILON;
```

it's based on level of accuracy you needed for comparison